# Open one LXTerminal at a time

Tags: bash, lxde, lxterminal, terminal

I am using .bashrc file to launch python scripts when lxterminal is launched.
The problem is that i don't want the user to be able to start another lxterminal and therefore retrigger the same scripts when they are actually running.
Is there a way to acheive this ?

Comment: You have already asked a question about launching a script using .bashrc, and accepted the answer. If you search this site you will find other answers explaining why .bashrc won't wprk.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. .bashrc is specifically designed to be run in every terminal a user logs in. If you don't need that, don't use .bashrc.